# How to automate geoserver installation using Chef?

Tags: geoserver

I need to automate a GeoServer installation on CENTOS 6.x using Chef.

I've found only this question about this issue,  [Automating removal of all demo layers from Geoserver](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33049/automating-removal-of-all-demo-layers-from-geoserver/33532#33532), but it's quite outdated

Any suggestions / examples updated?

Answer (score 2):

You can probably start with the [cookbook](https://github.com/ianturton/geoserver-vagrant/tree/master/local-cookbook/geoserver) from my [vagrant installer](https://github.com/ianturton/geoserver-vagrant).

It will fetch a version of GeoServer and unpack and install it, there are also examples of adding specific extensions. It has only been tested on Ubuntu systems but should be easy to port to RHEL/CENTOS - PRs are welcome.